# Javascript Jquery JSON posting - is my understanding correct?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Is my understanding correct:

```
// JavaScript, jQuery
$.ajax({
    url: '/post.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify({a: 'a', b: 'b'}),
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

$_POST will have 0 elements

Right now, PHP receives a string, not an object. So it can't iterate over it as key/values

There is no need to stringify since a JSON is already constructed.

This should work properly in this case:

```
// JavaScript, jQuery
$.ajax({
    url: '/post.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {a: 'a', b: 'b'},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent.

If you pass a string as the value of the `data` property, then that's what gets sent to the server. Objects are converted to a parameter string if you pass an object.

Servers expect parameters to be in the form of HTTP query strings:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

If you pass through a JSON string, it won't look like that and the server won't be able to do it's normal parameter handling. That's not necessarily wrong or bad, if you have server code that can handle the JSON.

Comment: For a little more clarity based on the example in OP: `JSON.stringify` will generate a string `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`, passing just the object directly will generate a string `key1=value1&key2=value2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/post.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {a: 'a', b: 'b'},
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

If you analyse the post that was sent to the server you will find:

```
a=a&b=b
```

So data got converted into query string without the need of `JSON.stringify`